# Modify the Frame of UIButton

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to resize a UIButton referenced from xib file.

This is what I've tried without success:

```
    RectangleF frame = actionBtn.Frame;

    frame.Width = 140;

    actionBtn.Frame = frame;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify an existing RectangleF.  Try this instead

```
RectangleF frame = actionBtn.Frame;

actionBtn.Frame = new RectangleF(frame.X, frame.Y, 140, frame.Height);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work either. Really strange.